# PHP: Access a variable that's declared in a function, within another function

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following:

```
class Submit extends \RightNow\Models\Base
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function inner () {
        return $i++;
    }
    function outer(){
        $i = 0;
        $this->inner();
        echo $i;
    }
}

$submit = new Submit();
$submit->outer();
```

How is it possible for `inner()` to access the variable $i that was declared in `outer()`? I've tried using `global` but this didn't work.

I understand in my very basic example, I could pass the variable in as a parameter but this just serves as an example for my question

I am using CodeIgniter

Comment: [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using **Codeigniter**, You can achieve it by the below code. In any class, you can use a class member variable in any of the member functions in the class.

```
class Submit extends \RightNow\Models\Base
 {
  public $i = 0;
  function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }
  function inner () {
    return $this->i++;
   }
  function outer(){
    $this->i = 0;
    inner();
    echo $this->i;
   }
  outer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all your methods are in a *class* you can use the below approach whereby the variable is a class reference set in the class and so automatically available to all class methods.

Variables in the class are called *properties*.

```
class Submit extends \RightNow\Models\Base
{
    private $i = 0; // set class based variable;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function inner () {
        return $this->i++;
    }
    function outer(){
       // $i = 0; You probably don't want to set this each call? 
        $this->inner();
        echo $this->i; 
    }
}

$submit = new Submit();
$submit->outer();
```

See above everything references the class property `$i` which is set in the class.

Alternatively if you're working with the same process over multiple varaibles from you can group them up into an `array` and simply pass the array as the single argument.

Your code will look slightly different depending on if the values are coming from inside or outside the class.

## References :

[PHP - passing variables to classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877851/php-passing-variables-to-classes)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

You can [pass a variable by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). E.g.:

```
function inner (&$i) {
    return $i++;
}

function outer(){
    $i = 0;
    inner($i);
    echo $i; // 1
}
```

**UPD**

If you want to pass multiple variables:

1. you can pass an array by reference:

```
function inner (&$arr) {
   $arr['i']++;
   $arr['j']--;
}

function outer() {
   $a = array('i' => 5, 'j' => 10);
   inner($a);
   echo $a['i'] . "\n" . $a['j']; // 6 9
}
```

2. You can pass an object. In this case it always passed by reference implicitly. E.g.

```
function inner($obj) { // no & needed, because it is an object reference itself
    $obj->a++;
    $obj->b--;
}


function outer() {
    $obj = new \stdClass();
    $obj->a = 5;
    $obj->b = 10;
    inner($obj);
    echo $obj->a . "\n" . $obj->b;  // 6 9
}
```

3. inside the same class you can use private members, but make sure the functions are not recursive (i.e. the same field is not reused simultaneously in different places):

```
class Submit extends \RightNow\Models\Base
{
    private $_i;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function inner () {
        $this->_i++;
    }
    function outer(){
        $this->_i = 0;
        $this->inner();
        echo $this->_i;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I had a dozen parameters, I'd have to do this a dozen times? That's the only way?